# How do I keep a Checkbox disabled in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have an application that pairs a textbox with a checkbox. The user can check the checkbox, which auto-populates the textbox with a specific dollar amount. If they uncheck the checkbox, this sets the textbox's value to zero. They can also enter a dollar amount in the textbox and an onblur event handler toggles the checkbox.

The problem comes when they enter a dollar amount in the textbox and then check the checkbox with a mouse click. This fires the onblur event, which automatically toggles the checkbox, then recognizes the mouse click, setting the dollar amount back to zero.

My solution was to disable the checkbox on textbox focus, then enable the checkbox on textbox onblur event.

This works well in Firefox and Chrome, but fails miserably in Internet Explorer. FF and Chrome ignore any mouse click on the checkbox when it is disabled. This means that the onblur event does not fire, when the user clicks on the disabled checkbox after entering a dollar amount in the textbox. The checkbox stays disabled. They have to click elsewhere on the page for it to be enabled.

In Internet Explorer, the onblur event fires when the user clicks on the disabled checkbox, and the checkbox recognizes the click, right after it is checked with the onblur event handler, unchecking the checkbox, setting the textbox value back to zero.

I need a better solution. How do I get Internet Explorer to act like FF and Chrome, ignoring any click on a disabled checkbox. Or, is there a more elegant solution altogether?

Example Code:

```
<input type=textbox id=textbox1 onFocus=CheckboxDisable('pairedWithTextBox1'); onBlur=CheckboxEnable('pairedWithTextBox1');>
<input type=checkbox id=pairedWithTextBox1>
```

Javascript code:

```
function CheckboxDisable(id){
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
}

function CheckboxEnable(id){
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: You could remove the event? You've tagged **jQuery**, so look at the [`off` function](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: What is the actual use case? It sounds like the root cause is a confusing design... English-speakers (can't speak for others) generally read documents and fill out forms from top-to-bottom, left-to-right. It seems a bit counterintuitive to put a checkbox to the right of a textbox that updates the textbox. If your user just finished entering data in the textbox (doing some work) they will be annoyed if they click something that just blows away their work and defaults it again. Can you provide a less generic example? (more specific the better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of a real solution. .. you **COULD** set a data attribute on the check box on focus of the text element, then check for it on the cb on click event and override the default action. ..

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a possibly confusing user interface design (can't say for sure since you genericized the problem too much), the problem is that the checkbox and textbox are both *views* of the same *model*.

- The *model* is the dollar amount.
- The textbox is a *view* of the
  actual dollar amount.
- The checkbox is a *view* that indicates
  whether the amount is `0` or something else.

Your current design is complex, which is not by itself a bad thing, because the event handlers for the text box `onblur` and checkbox `onclick` are also *controllers* of the model. (This is a bit of an oversimplification; the *controller* also consists of the browser and all the JavaScript code.)

Here is a solution that helps illustrate this fact. It works based on the business rule that once the user has modified the value in the textbox (to a non-zero value) changing the state of the checkbox from unchecked to checked will not update the model (or the textbox *view*).

```js
var txtAmount = document.getElementById('txtAmount');
var chkAmount = document.getElementById('chkAmount');
var defaultValue = 0;
var model = defaultValue;

function UpdateViews() {
    if (model === 0) {
        chkAmount.checked = false;
    }
    txtAmount.value = model.toFixed(2);
}

function UpdateModel(val) {
    // update model when view changes
    model = parseFloat(val) || defaultValue;
    UpdateViews();
}
UpdateViews(); // set initial view

txtAmount.onchange = function () {
    UpdateModel(this.value);
};
chkAmount.onclick = function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        // when user checks the box, only update model if not yet modified
        if (model === defaultValue) UpdateModel(55); // hardcoded default of $55
    } else {
        UpdateModel(defaultValue);
    }
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtAmount' />
<input type='checkbox' id='chkAmount' />
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the user to have to check the checkbox and the summing of the totals is based on those checkboxes that are checked. I guess I COULD sum the totals exclusively from values in the textboxes, making the checkboxes sort of optional, only for selecting a total dollar value or setting it to zero. Though that seems less intuitive.

Comment: That is exactly the problem domain-specific details that you should add to your question. People posting answers on this site want to help you! And we will be able to help you better if you are more specific. There may be a design pattern better suited to what you are doing. Can you post a screenshot at least? Preferably post some markup (HTML) that illustrates what you are actually doing, even if it is a simplified example. What you have right now is a design problem where the textbox and checkbox are chasing each other around..

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your case, I will put an If-Else in the click event of the checkbox...

Something like:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) | textBox1.Text != "0")
        {
            // Do nothing since textbox1 already has a value greater than zero
        }
        else
        {
            // Enter amount in textbox
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. A user may want to uncheck the checkbox to change the dollar amount to zero. This would prevent them from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function CheckboxDisable(id){

$("#id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function CheckboxEnable(id){
    $("#id").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here?